# Why did my switch spark when I installed it in a metal junction box?

Tags: switch, wifi, smart-switch

Okay, so I put in a new Wifi Light Switch. The box was metal and tiny, while the switch was big and all of the screws were on the bottom of the switch. Why did it spark and blow up? Was it because all four screws hit the box? I just want to know, because I am going to get a plastic box replacement, and i want to know if that's all I need to do to assure it never happens again.

Comment: Which brand Wifi Light Switch?

Comment: Where country are you in? Is the WiFi switch UL listed? Can you post pictures?

Comment: It was a Nexete Smart Wifi Touch Switch.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box, please?

Comment: `was it because all four screws hit the box` .... why do you assume that all four screws would have to hit the box? .... why don't you look for burn marks on the switch screws and on the inside of the box?

Comment: Which screw was put through a wire?

Comment: [That switch](https://www.amazon.com/Assistant-Control-Function-Required-Single-Pole/dp/B078ZNJNZQ) doesn't look like it was designed for the US market.  Not sure where OP is, but that looks a little too non-standard for me to put in my house.

Comment: What does "blow up" mean? You shouldn't be working on electrical things without a basic understanding of circuitry. Yes, contacting the hot conductor to a grounded box makes for a show. Replacing your box isn't the solution.

Comment: @JPhi1618, are you sure about that?  It's ETL and FCC listed, it's looking for 120V at 60Hz, and the wiring diagram follows US color codes, so I'm pretty sure it's intended for the US/North American market only.

Comment: @NateStrickland I'm just saying the design is non-standard.  I'm trying to imagine getting 4 #14 wires under those small screws all along that narrow bottom edge of the switch.  Most national brand switches would use pigtails or would have larger (standard sized) screws along the sides.  Technically certified for use in the US and designed to meet the expectations/norms of the US electrical industry are different things.

Comment: @JPhi1618, those screws aren't for putting wires under -- you put the wires through the holes in the back, then tighten the screws to clamp a plate down on them, just like modern back-wire receptacles.  It looks different than a standard switch, but there's really nothing wrong with this wiring method.

Comment: @JPhi1618 also ETL (Intertek) apparently listed it. They're supposed be on par with UL.

Comment: @JPhi1618 -- the setup on the switch sounds like an Eurostyle terminal block, which is OK for mains devices in the US (some of the more exotic Lutron stuff uses them), just unconventional

Answer (score 4):

Don't downgrade to a plastic box.  Metal boxes are **better** and what's more, they are often essential in distributing **grounding** to other boxes.  Further in some cities (e.g. Chicago) they are *required by Code*.

The purpose of a box is to provide grounding and fire protection, and metal boxes do that better than plastic ones in all respects.  Plastic boxes exist to be *cheap*, so builders can save $20 per house.

Metal boxes also allow there to be fewer (or no!) ground *wires* in the box.  For instance this smart switch doesn't need a ground wire since it can ground via the yoke and screws.

This is a quality product with an ETL listing (equivalent to UL listed). Bad designs just won't clear that listing process, so I don't buy "all 4 screws bottomed out on the box".  Far more likely:

- A wayward bare ground wire in the box touched one of the screws (feels unlikely)
- Wires were over-stripped, leaving bare length sticking out.  This contacted a ground wire.

The screw issue could be annulled with a couple layers of electrical tape across them.  *That's* how you solve that problem (if it even is a problem).

Comment: More builder bashing. It's basic economics--the consumer buys the cheaper house, all visible features being equal. That's not the builder's fault. Have you tried to sell homes up against "square foot builders"? It's not easy. That aside, it costs a lot more than $20 to install metal. There's a lot more labor involved. It might amount to many $hundreds.